# Oracle Apex How to display page item as url

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a page item which stores URL.

How do i change its type to URL so that the link becomes clickable.

As of now, there is page subtype url, but setting it doesn't make any difference.

[image]

Apex 21.1

Comment: Is it an editable page item or read only ?

Comment: Its read only page item

Comment: Ah... that changes the question entirely. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A text field is an html input element, that will display text only, you probably could write some javascript to open whatever is in the page item in an url but that is confusing functionality. What should happen if the user clicks in the input element ? Should it open the link or should the user be editing the value ?
This is a possibility.

1. Create a page item on your page, say `P1_URL`
2. Add the following in the "Post Text" attribute of the page item (style it to your own preference):

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" id="myurl"><span class="fa fa-external-link" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
```

3. Add a dynamic action on change of the element  `P1_URL` with a true action of "Execute Javascript Code" and the following code:

```
$("#myurl").attr("href", apex.item( "P13_URL" ).getValue())
```

4. Check "Fire on Initialization" for the true action.

That is all there is to it, now when you add something in the page item `P1_URL` and click the link, it will open the that url in a new window.

**UPDATE**: Technique for read only text field.
For a read only text field, the input element is hidden and an additional span element is rendered with an the page item name as id, suffixed by _DISPLAY. The trick is to grab the content of that span element and add an anchor with attributes. This can be done with an onload dynamic action:

1. Create a page item on your page, say `P1_URL`, set it to "Read-Only: Always"
2. Add a dynamic action on Page Load with a true action of "Execute Javascript Code" and the following code:

```
let itemVal = $("#P1_URL_DISPLAY").text()
$("#PP1_URL_DISPLAY").html(`<a href='${itemVal}' target='_blank'>${itemVal}</a>`)
```

Make sure that when you copy this, the quotes are exactly the same: the outer quotes are backticks, those are needed for the ES6 syntax.

Note: check the page documentation for the subtype url - it explains exactly what it does.